# Can calling available() for a BufferedInputStream lead me astray in this case?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am reading in arbitrary size file in blocks of 1021 bytes, with a block size of <= 1021 bytes for the final block of the file. At the moment, I am doing this using a `BufferedInputStream` which is wrapped around a `FileInputStream` and code that looks (roughly) like the following (where `reader` is the `BufferedInputStream` and this is operating in a loop):

```
int availableData = reader.available();
int datalen = (availableData >= 1021) 
                ? 1021 
                : availableData;
reader.read(bufferArray, 0, datalen);
```

However, from reading the API docs, I note that `available()` only gives an "estimate" of the available size, before the call would 'block'. Printing out the value of `availableData` each iteration seems to give the expected values - starting with the file size and slowly getting less until it is <= 1021. Given that this is a local file, am I wrong to expect this to be a correct value - is there a situation where `available()` would give an incorrect answer?

**EDIT:** Sorry, additional information. The `BufferedInputStream` is wrapped around a `FileInputStream`. From the source code for a FIS, I think I'm safe to rely on available() as a measure of how much data is left in the case of a local file. Am I right?

Comment: Keep in mind: the underlying stream might return available 0 (w/o blocking) and if there is no prebuffered data in the BufferedInputStream, you end up calling read w/ len = 0... which exits immediately. Make sure you don't call read w/ zero len. FileInputStream tends to return the remaining data length, however that's also a problem if you attempt to read too large file.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid blocking instead of just reading the file with a fixed buffer size of 1021?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pointless. Those four lines of code are entirely equivalent to this:

```
reader.read(buffer, 0, 1021);
```

without the timing-window problem you have introduced between the available() call and the read. Note that this code is still incorrect as you are ignoring the return value, which can be -1 at EOS, or else anything between 1 and 1021 inclusive.

Comment: How is that equivalent? What if the amount of data left to be read is < 1021? I end up with a buffer of size 1021, but with less than 1021 bytes of data in it - how do I tell where the data ends? Right now I use the `datalen` variable to tell me how big the buffer should be. Do I not need to do this?

Comment: read() returns the number of bytes it actually read, or -1 at EOS.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give the estimated size, it gives the remaining bytes that can be read. It's not an estimate with `BufferedInputStream`.

> Returns the number of bytes that can
>   be read from this input stream without
>   blocking.

You should pass `available()` directly into the `read()` call if you want to avoid blocking, but remember to return if the return value is 0 or -1. `available()` might throw an exception on buffer types that don't support the operation.

Comment: Right, thank you for the information. What exactly might cause a local file to block, and why would passing available() straight to read help prevent this?

Comment: Is there anything else working on the file at the same time? If there is, then available() would be unsafe to prevent blocking.

Comment: 'The number of bytes that can be read without blocking' doesn't mean 'the remaining bytes that can be read'.

Comment: Well, you know the number of total available bytes from the file size, obviously :)